# Guitar strings sound muted when playing them normally

Tags: guitar

Hey all so my guitar when playing on the A, D, B, and high E while playing through frets 1-7 sound muted. However the rest of the frets seem to be fine on all of these strings.I know im not muting them by accident because I’ve been playing guitar for a while now.Thanks for reading :)

Comment: We're going to need *waaaaay* more details than that. Electric guitar? Brand of guitar/equipment? Et cetera...

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like your neck relief is off. That’s the intentional very slight curve of the neck of the guitar to keep the strings from hitting the frets when they vibrate.

If you’ve never set your neck relief before, the best thing to do is take it to a guitar tech or luthier to have them adjust it.